# How doomed are you if you are shot in the post apocalypse?

Tags: post-apocalypse, medical

So, to set the stage, society collapses, we still have people, technology, and cities, but we are all having to kill each other, for food, probably. Of course, there are still doctors and surgeons and medics, but they are likely already dead or have joined a faction. You probably don't have access to that medical care. But you might have scavenged some medical supplies, at worst, it's some bandages, at best, its professional surgical equipment (not that you know what you're doing or that you can operate on yourself anyway).

So, you've been shot, it doesn't matter as much where, but point is you're hit. How dead are you? Assuming no vital organs have been hit, would you just be able to patch yourself up and live or would you need surgery for a gunshot wound no matter what? We aren't dealing with infections either, right now our only threat is the wound itself. Can you stop the bleeding and eventually make a full or at least full enough recovery that it's no longer causing you to die? Surgery isn't an option unless you can do it on yourself and its simple enough that someone with a basic understanding of anatomy and medical procedures can do it. And you probably only have bandages and stitches anyway.

Comment: "you've been shot, it doesn't matter as much where". Sorry, it does matter a lot. Or are you asking for a complete book on every possible shot location on a human body, with different degrees of damage?

Comment: Agree with LDutch, it also matters what you are shot with - .22 short and .50 BMG are going to have very different results.  Unanswerable without wound location and weapon/ammunition information.

Comment: Agree with both of you, but it also matters what is in between you and the bullet being fired. Point blank range with nothing between you or 2000 yards and wearing body armor is a pretty big difference.

Comment: VTC Too Story-Based. Someone is as dead as you, the worldbuilder, want them to be. What does your story say? Were they shot near a large community or a small one? Were they shot in the leg or in the heart or brain? Was the bullet a hollow-point or armor-piercing? Was the gun low-velocity or high? Are there medical supplies nearby or not? Is there water nearby or not? Is there cloth for bandages nearby or not? Frankly, there are back alleys in today's world where you have a lower chance of surviving a gunshot than in any post-apocalyptic world.

Answer (score 6):

About as dead as people where in 1400 or 1600 when they were shot. You know, those dark ages, when life was supposedly nasty, brutish, and short?

- The casualty would benefit from *knowledge*, like the germ theory of disease. You excluded that, but it is the **main** killer in this situation.
- The casualty would suffer from *lack of knowledge*, like medicines which do not come out of a blister pack.
- The *breakdown of society* would reduce supporting care.

So if you want your character to live, he or she pours booze over the wound, uses bandages cleaned in boiling water, etc., and lives. If you want the character to die, he or she does all that and gets sepsis, anyway.

It would also make a big difference if the [ventral body cavity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_cavity#Ventral_body_cavity) is perforated, or just the extremeties.